# access to the port 'com8' is denied. Where's the error in this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

i'm trying to get data from a serial device, but program is running with this error "access to the port 'com8' is denied". please give a solution.

```
public void PorttInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM8");

        try
        {
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            //mySerialPort.Close();
        }
    }
    public String data;
    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

        String dataInput = sp.ReadExisting();
        data = dataInput;
    }
```

Comment: There might be another process that already has it open.

Comment: COM ports generally aren't shared, so if something else is already connected to it you will have your access denied. Additionally if your computer doesn't actually have a COM8 port the access will be denied. You should try checking to make sure you have a COM8 port before you try and connect to it. check out https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners for a pretty in depth c# serial port tutorial

Comment: Looks like there's no other place in your code that closes the port other than when an exception has occurred. You should always close your port graceful after you no longer need the port or upon app exit.

Comment: Quick suggestion -- verify ability to use COM port with terminal program like putty or TeraTerm just to make sure port is working and accessible.

Comment: @bobwki Its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

If in the IDE your serial report output windows(Serial Monitor) is open, you will face with this error. So close that window and then upload your code